# Cakephp Undefined Index

Tags: cakephp, indexing

When creating a view I am getting a `undefined index error: Account`  on the line with `$senderName['Account']['company_name']`but when debugging the variable the array prints out

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Account' => array(
            'id' => '0',
            'street' => 'SYSTEM',
            'city' => 'SYSTEM',
            'postcode' => '0',
            'state' => 'SYS',
            'country' => 'SYS',
            'active' => true,
            'company_name' => 'SYSTEM',
            'abn' => '0'
        ),
        'Template' => array(),
        'User' => array(),
        'Invoice' => array()
    ),
```

here is the code for my view

```
<?php foreach($invoice as $invoices):?>
                <?php foreach($senderName as $senderName):?>
                <?php foreach($receiverName as $receiverName):?>
                    <tr> 
                <tr>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $senderName['Account']['company_name']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $receiverName['Account']['company_name']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $this->Form->Html->link($invoices['Invoice']['id'],
                                    array('controller' => 'Invoices','action'=>'viewinvoice',$invoices['Invoice']['id'])); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and just in case here is my related function

```
        $accounts2=$this->User->find('list', array(
        'fields'=>array('account_id'),
        'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));


        $invoices=$this->Invoice->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'Invoice.receiver_id' => $accounts2)));

        $sender=$this->Invoice->Find('list', array('fields'=>('sender_id')));
        $receiver=$this->Invoice->Find('list', array('fields'=>('receiver_id')));

        $senderName=$this->Account->Find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'id'=>array_values($sender))));

        $receiverName=$this->Account->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'id'=>array_values($receiver))));
debug($senderName);

        $this->set('senderName', $senderName);
        $this->set('accounts2', $accounts2); 
        $this->set('receiverName', $receiverName); 
        $this->set('sender',$sender);
        $this->set('receiver',$receiver);
        $this->set('invoice', $invoices);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should review your code in view :

```
<?php foreach($senderName as $senderName):?>
<?php foreach($receiverName as $receiverName):?>
```

in foreach array_expression and value variable should be different but you have used same variable name, please use different names for this.

Answer (score 3):

You're computer is right. :)

```
$senderName['Account']['company_name']
```

does not exists.

```
$senderName['0']['Account']['company_name']
```

does.

The data comes in this format as they may be several account liked to senderName.

Edit:

Could you give the relationship in your models too?